# How to Copy a data range from one sheet to another sheet using Google Sheet Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Disclaimer: I am just new in coding and I just want to automate things up in my work.

I want to copy a data from 'Data Entry' sheet to another sheet specified by the cell in 'Data Entry' sheet.

here is the code that I am using:

```js
function DataEntry() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data Entry');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  let rowCount = sourceValues.length();
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length();

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('6');
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1,rowCount,columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

In the source sheet, I want to copy the data starting from row 3, column L. (the number of rows varies every data batch)

Then in the target sheet, which will be specified by a cell in source sheet (cell T2). The pasting should start at row 2, column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function DataEntry() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data Entry');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  let sheetName = sourceValues[1][19];
  sourceValues = sourceValues.slice(2).map(row => row.slice(11));

  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1,rowCount,columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

#### Explanation:

- Since [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2D array, in order to get the value from a certain cell you just have to use the appropriate array indexes to access the desired element (in this case, `1` and `19`, corresponding to `T2`).
- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to retrieve a subset of the range values. You could also retrieve the corresponding range directly (e.g. `sourceSheet.getRange("L3:L").getValues().flat().filter(String)`), but in this way you are minimizing the amount of calls to the spreasdheet service, which is [a good practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).

Comment: Tried it and there was an error in line 10

Comment: it works now, jI just removed () in   let rowCount = sourceValues.length();
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length(); thanks a lot!

Comment: Corrected. `length` is not a method. I copied your original code and that was wrong.

Comment: Hello there again! I amplaying around with the code that you provided. This just comes into my mind, let's say that I only need 6 columns to be copied, is that possible?

Comment: Change `slice(11)` to `slice(11, 11+6)`

Comment: one more thing, I hope I am not annoying you in some ways. What if the target sheet has data and I want to overwrite it? I have noticed that if the target sheet has data in it, the data being transferred is being moved to the first column without data

Comment: I am sorry I cannot get your problem. `setValues` would overwrite all values in the `targetRange`.

Comment: @iamblichus sorry to bring this up again, I was reading your explanation, and I am wondering how am I going to apply the thing that you mentioned in the second dot. Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding this, I'm just new to this.

Comment: @Mr.YJY `I am wondering how am I going to apply the thing that you mentioned in the second dot` The good thing is that idfurw already did it for you, just look at the code :)

Comment: Hello, sorry if I keep coming back, this is also connected to this, how to limit the rows to be copied based on the rows that only has data? So, blank rows will be ignored.